# remove //xx after directory in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all URLs like this:

```
example.com/podcasts//rebt
```

to

```
example.com/podcasts
```

I am trying to adjust this code to do both but I can't get it to work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(/{2,})(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is `/podcasts` (or whatever "directory") a physical directory on the filesystem? In your code, what is `%3` expected to contain? In your example you are removing everything after the double slash?

Comment: /podcasts is a url path.  The old squarespace account had put in the //   All the old links should be redirected just to /podcasts.  I was attempting to strip everything after then first / of the double //.  I think this was the wrong code to start with. :(

Answer (score 0):

To remove `//<something>` at the end of the URL-path (eg. `/podcasts//rebt` to `/podcasts`, try the following instead at the top of the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^?]+?)//
RewriteRule . %1 [R=301,L]
```

`THE_REQUEST` server variable contains the first line of the initial request headers (eg. `GET /podcasts/rebt HTTP/1.1`) and does not change when the request is internally rewritten (unlike `REQUEST_URI`).

The regex `\s([^?]+?)//` captures the part of the URL-path before the first instance of a double slash. Anything after and including the double slash, are discarded. This regex also ensures we do not inadvertently match against the query string (if any).

The `%1` backreference contains the captured subpattern (ie. everything before the first double slash in the URL-path) from the preceding *CondPattern*.

*Aside:* Note that this will not work properly if the preceding URL-path maps to a physical directory, since it will result in two redirects. eg. `/directory//something` to `/directory` to `/directory/` (by mod_dir). In this case, you should avoid removing the first trailing slash.

You should test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid any potential caching issues and only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect when you are sure it's working as intended. You should clear your browser cache before testing.

---

**A look at your existing rule...**

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(/{2,})(.*)$
> RewriteRule . %1/%3 [R=301,L]
> ```

This code is intended to reduce multiple slashes to single slashes in the URL-path, not *remove* the double slash and remaining path entirely. eg. `/podcasts//rebt` to `/podcasts/rebt`. However, since it checks against the `REQUEST_URI` server variable (which can change throughout the request) it may not work as intended.

Also, the condition that checks against the `REQUEST_METHOD` would seem to be redundant, unless you are erroneously POSTing to double-slashed URLs internally? A 301 redirect removes any POST data (since the browser converts it to GET) - hence why the check may be necessary in certain cases.